# reversing without IDA or OLLYDBG

Tags: ida, ollydbg

I am blind, and both IDA and OllyDBG don't wrok with my screenreader.  What are my best choices for reverse engineering tools for both windows and linux?

I am somewhat familiar with both gdb and windbg, but was wondering if there is something else to consider

Comment: Try Radare2. It is one of the best and it might work...

Comment: Are you try x64dbg by screenreader?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, IDA does work with screenreaders (at least with recent JAWS on Windows; I'm not 100% sure what the situation is with Linux ATM); we (Hex-Rays) happen to have a few blind users and worked with them to make recent IDA versions accessible. The IDA Free 5.0 (Windows only) is still using Borland VCL for GUI and AFAIK is accessible to some screenreaders.

I'm not familiar much with other tools and especially their accessibility, but I suspect Radare2, being console-oriented, should be somewhat friendly to screen readers.

You can also always use just plain linear disassemblers (`objdump`, `dumpbin`, or even IDA in batch mode) and edit the disassembly listing manually, or even dump hex and work from it...